# 3D rotation like credit card in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to provide some 3D rotation of images, like credit card (please check the video in the [link](http://footage.shutterstock.com/clip-212878-stock-footage-rotating-credit-card.html))

I want to know is it feasible or not, in the case of Android. If yes, how can I do that.

The card must have some thickness.

Answer (score 5):

It definitely is feasible, but you will have to do some studying:-).

Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

But you may also achieve your goal by just using the video you have posted in your link.

Comment: Thank you for quick response, how can I use this video to achieve my goal? here we are images on the card are not fixed (it may change by the end user)

Comment: Oh, than the video is not an option. How much time do you have for the task? Because, as stated below, learning OpenGL is going to be rather time consuming.

Comment: I have only 3 days to do this

Comment: Well, if you are bright and can spend whole three days o it, you can do it. I have experience working with OpenGL on PCs, it is very interesting stuff. start here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html

Comment: thanks for giving grt information, and I am using 3D cube for this rotation by appending images to the front and back sides of the cube, and for thickness part am appending white images to the bathe sides. its working fine for sharp edged images, not for rounded edged images. how can I do this?

Comment: Great, I am glad you did it! With the rotation, it is too specific a question for me, you should start a new SO Thread on this. Also, if my answer helped you, you should accept it so others can see it as a solved problem and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Some context would be useful such as will this be a loading screen? Something in video? etc?

For instance, if you are trying to make a website style layout and have the card up at the top always spinning, I would advice against that on any mobile device as its a waste of performance.

If instead you are using it as a loading screen then again I would advice against it as you are going to spend a lot of time initializing open gl and loading the texture and mesh for the card as well as any lighting you need and then initiate animators and do the spinning etc.

As previously stated OpenGL would be a way of doing this; however, this is not a simple few lines of code. This would be quite the undertaking for someone unfamiliar with OpenGL and 3D modeling to accomplish in a short time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Question: do you require a native Android app, or would it be alright to use Flash Player?  You can find tons of interactive 3d geometry demos on http://wonderfl.net - I forked one that had a plane, switched it to a cube, and you can download the results -

[3d box on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/zzVu)

Not OpenGL - the example I found was Papervision3D (which is out of date a couple of years) - but software rendering is fine for 12 triangles.  You, of course, would have to import your card faces as texture images if you want to make it look like a credit card.